# How to use jQuery .live() with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Currently I am using [John Resig's LiveQuery plugin/function](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/) to allow users to sort through a long unordered-list of list-items. The code is as follows: `$('input#q').liveUpdate('ul#teams').focus();` The issue arises when I use ajaxified tabs to sort the lists. Essentially I use ajax to pull in different lists and the `liveUpdate()` function doesn't have access to the new li's.

I assume I would need to bind this using the [`.live()` function](http://api.jquery.com/live/). But I am unclear how to bind this to an ajax event, I've only used the "click" event. How would I bind the new `liveUpdate()` to the newly loaded list-items?

**EDIT:**
The ajax tabs is run through the wordpress ajax api so the code is fairly complex, but simplified it is something like this:

```
$('div.item-list-tabs').click( function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).parent();

    var data = {action, scope, pagination}; // Passes action to WP that loads my tab data
    $.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $(target).fadeOut( 100, function() {
            $(this).html(response);
            $(this).fadeIn(100);
        });
     });

     return false;
});
```

This is simplified for the sake of this conversation, but basically once the `$.post` loads the response in place `.liveUpdate()` doesn't have access to it. I believe the `.live()` function is the answer to this problem, I'm just unclear on how to implement it with the `$.post()`

Comment: Can you please post code you are using for your “ajaxified tabs” ?

Comment: I've edited the original post with the ajax-tabs js

Answer (score 4):

As mentionned in the documentation of JQuery, .live() is considered deprecated. You should use the method .on() instead.

```
$("#yourSelector").on("click", function() {
    // statement
});
```

To also manage futur object of the selector type, you can use .on() like this

```
$(document).on("click", "#yourSelector", function() {
    // statement
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jQuery's Ajax Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

```
$('input#q').ajaxComplete(function(){
    $(this).liveUpdate('ul#teams').focus();

    $(this).unbind('ajaxStop');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got trouble with using just

```
$('selector').click(function(..
```

after an Ajax call, and finally found that we need to use

```
$('selector').live("click", function(){..
```

or the new method

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function(){..
```

to bind the event for new elements created after an Ajax call.

```
$(document).on('click','selector', function(event){
//your code    
});
```

For live

```
$('selector').live('click', function(event){    
//your code    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#q').live(function() {
   $(this).liveUpdate('ul#teams').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.item-list-tabs").live("click",function(){
//statements..
});
```